# Can't pass json from html to javascript in Flask?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, json

I want to pass the json file to javascript, and print it as a html table.But I've tried many methods and they all don't work.
Here is my Flask code:

```
@app.route('/details/', methods=['GET'])
def details():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        mongoClient = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
        name = session['name']
        print name
        db = mongoClient[name]
        results = db[name].find()
        json_results= []
        for result in results:
            json_results.append(result)
        json_tmp = toJson(json_results)
        return render_template('details.html', pass_tmp=json_tmp)
```

Here is my html code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block scripts %}
    {{ super() }}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myList = {{ pass_tmp }}
        // Builds the HTML Table out of myList json data from Ivy restful service.
         function buildHtmlTable() {
             var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList);

             for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
                 var row$ = $('<tr/>');
                 for (var colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < columns.length ; colIndex++) {
                     var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];

                     if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }

                     row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
                 }
                 $("#excelDataTable").append(row$);
             }
         }

         // Adds a header row to the table and returns the set of columns.
         // Need to do union of keys from all records as some records may not contain
         // all records
         function addAllColumnHeaders(myList)
         {
             var columnSet = [];
             var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

             for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
                 var rowHash = myList[i];
                 for (var key in rowHash) {
                     if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1){
                         columnSet.push(key);
                         headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
                     }
                 }
             }
             $("#excelDataTable").append(headerTr$);

             return columnSet;
         }
    </script>
{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
{#    <input type="button" onclick="display_alert()" value="点击显示提示框" />#}
    <body onload="buildHtmlTable()">
    <table id="excelDataTable" border="1">
    </table>
    </body>
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see, I've tried this method `var myList = {{ pass_tmp }}`, but there is no result in my webpage.
I've set the variable `myList` fixed,e.g.:

```
var myList=[{"Status": " complete ", "Name": " Fecal viral communites from wild urban brown rats in Berlin, Germany - KS/11/0579 ", "Add_Date": " 2016-04-08 ", "Link": "?id=Gp0138564", "_id": {"$oid": "57159666b5492a881a2bb87e"}, "Id": "Gp0138564"}, {"Status": " incomplete ", "Name": " Fecal viral communites from wild urban brown rats in Berlin, Germany - KS/11/0578 ", "Add_Date": " 2016-04-08 ", "Link": "?id=Gp0138563", "_id": {"$oid": "57159666b5492a881a2bb87f"}, "Id": "Gp0138563"}, {"Status": " incomplete ", "Name": " Fecal viral communites from wild urban brown rats in Berlin, Germany - KS/11/0577 ", "Add_Date": " 2016-04-08 ", "Link": "?id=Gp0138562", "_id": {"$oid": "57159666b5492a881a2bb880"}, "Id": "Gp0138562"}];
```

It turns out the javascript code is correct, there is a html table in my webpage like this:
[image]

So I just want to know how to pass the json variable `pass_tmp` to javascript as `myList` and continue the further parse?

Comment: Pass in `results` directly to your template, then use `var myList = {{ results|tojson|safe }};` to convert the list to JSON in the template using the Flask JSON converter (which also makes your JSON HTML safe), and tell the template not to escape the result with `|safe`; it is already escaped by that point.

Comment: I didn't pass a list, you can see from my code that the variable `pass_tmp` is already as json format.So it's different from what other questions said.

Comment: First part of my comment: *Pass in `results` directly to your template*. I'm telling you to not do the JSON encoding in your function, but to do so in the template. `tojson` applies escaping that makes it safe to interpolate into a script tag in a HTML page.

Comment: At any rate, your problem is almost certainly auto-escaping related. That, or your list is simply empty.

Comment: So it's not correct to pass a json file directly to template,I should convert it to json format in my template?

Comment: Yes, because the `tojson` filter provided explicitly handles JSON that'll be embedded in a HTML template.

Comment: I have thought it as empty, but I print it in html, it turns out not empty.

Comment: Right, but that wasn't clear from your question, so I had to cover that base. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll pay attention next time I ask question.Now I have to deal with the problem`TypeError:ObjectID is not JSON serializable`.  _(:зゝ∠)_